# Ubuntu Desktop 20.10 on Raspberry Pi 4 8GB 1TB SSD freeze except for mouse pointer

Tags: mouse, ssd, freeze, raspberrypi, 20.10

Hardware specs:

- Raspberry pi 4 8GB
- Geekworm X829 + X735 casing
- SSD 1TB Samsung 860 EVO
- USB2.0 Keyboard and Mouse connected
- Network cable connected
- Adapter is the Geekworm provided 5V 4A

Installed Ubuntu desktop onto an SD-card to boot RPI with Ubuntu desktop
following the Ubuntu Tutorial provided on this site (*https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-desktop-on-raspberry-pi-4#4-optional-usb-boot*).

After first boot and installation onto the SD-card, changed the boot order by step 4 of the Tutorial.

Formatted the SSD with the tool Disk of the Ubuntu desktop with no problems of freezing the RPI.

Download and installed the Ubuntu desktop 20.10 while running the RPi from the SD-card and wrote it on the SSD.

Shutdown the RPI, removed the SD-card and booted 1st time from the SSD.

Now installed the Ubuntu desktop on the SSD.

After the necessary reboots and update/upgrade got a working RPI 4 8GB with Ubuntu Desktop 20.10.

Then the problems started.

Problem:
Rapsberry Pi Freeze while running a terminal command and Firefox open.
Only reaction is the mouse pointer on the screen.
When the system freeze I can perform `Alt` `F2`/`F8` then do a login.
After login the mouse-pointer will reveal the screen like scratching a lottery billet, revealing what is under the login screen with the actual first running desktop scene.

First thing done was turn off the sleep modus of the screen. (Didn't solve the freeze.)

Running a terminal command `reboot` to reboot the system restarts the RPi with Ubuntu Desktop.

Need to check if it's start missing the connection to the SSD drive or what's really freezing the RPI.

As I was trying to compile FreeCAD 0.19 on it and having all those freezing problems it didn't compile yet.

Any additional information needed can be provided.

Any commands I can run to check the reason of the freeson (freezing)?

ls -al /var/crash

mentions

_usr_libexec_gnome-shell-calendar-server.1000.crash

looking into the gnome shell calendar server I found that this was fixed with a patch in gnome-shell 3.38.4 but 20.10 is based on 3.38.1 any help on how to install the fix? [bugs Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1885346)

Update with what ***seems*** to be the solution:

Under `Software & Updates` `Developer Options` `Pre-released updates (groovy-proposed)` activated, update and reboot.

This gave me a still reliable system without errors so far about the gnome-shell-calendar-server nor the freeze.

Meanwhile FreeCAD 0.19 was build and runs.

Will update when problem comes back.

Update:20201212

The problem with the gnome shell calendar server comes back. The workaround didn't catch the newer version. Still on the older 3.38.1 instead of the .4 :-(

But the hanging system didn't came back till now. So for that part it's worth to get the pre-released setting on.

Kind Regards,

XSZ.

P.S. Got an error once before the solution about blk_update_request [blk_update_request](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/777) Need to test if this is solved to.

Comment: Did the following adding the in [Software & Updates] [Developer Options] [V][Pre-released .] This made my RPi 4 8GB running Ubuntu Desktop 20.10 64 bit a little more stable.

Comment: The problem persist due to the Gnome Shell Calendar Server. based on the 3.38.1 in the official download, while the problem was resolved in the 3.38.4 version. Unable to install the gnome-shell 3.38.4 version to solve the hanging on the gnome-shell-calendar-server. Anuone who can point me to the correct way to install it on the RPi 4?